# Image count when referencing is wrong, but below the figure it is correct

Tags: graphics, hyperref

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGUFu.png

It seems that the numbering system refers to the section rather than the images. Moreover, when clicking the number it takes you to the start of the section that contains it, not at the real label.

For images I use:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \label{fig:proc_func}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{img/proc_func}
    \caption{Effects of non-continuous sampling.}
\end{figure}
```

Just saying: I have a page which is shown horizontal and that contains an image (I use package pdflscape), but removing it does not solve the problem.

These are my packages. I am using pdfLatex to compile.

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[urlcolor=blue, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotating}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={170mm,257mm},
    left=35mm,
    right=35mm,
    top=20mm,
}
```

I'm thinking that `hyperref` is to blame, but I haven't changed its option.

Comment: Nothing to do with `hyperref`. Move the `\label` after or within the `\caption`.

Comment: By the way, `hyperref` should be loaded last for most documents. But this is independent of the label stuff.